# Python (Tkinter) __init__ limitations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a limit to the number of entries into an **init** method in Python? I'm building a simple UI with Tkinter, and properly written labels are being ignored by the compiler when being referenced by other methods.

The code:

```
from tkinter import *    
from tkinter import ttk


class UI:

  def __init__(self, root):

    self.entryString = StringVar()
    self.entryString.set("50000000") #Default value     

    self.trialField = Entry(root, textvariable = self.entryString).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

    self.trialSend = Button(root, text = "Send value", command = self.setter()).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    #self.defaultTrials = Button(root, text = "Default", command = self.resetTrials).grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    self.staticLabel = Label(root, text = "This gets sent to program when program is run:").grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 3)

    self.trialOut = Label(root, text = self.entryString.get())
    self.trialOut.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2)        

  def setter(self):
    self.trialOut.config(text = self.entryString.get())
```

yet, I get the error: "AttributeError: 'UI' object has no attribute 'trialOut'"

There have been occasions wherein I can move the trialOut section to the top and it works just fine. I'm still learning to use Python and Tkinter, so I could have easily overlooked something. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
self.trialSend = Button(root, text = "Send value", command = self.setter()).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
```

Note that you are *calling* `self.setter` which references `self.trialOut`, however `self.trialOut` isn't defined until a few lines later.

You probably want:

```
self.trialSend = Button(root, text = "Send value", command = self.setter).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
```

(note the missing parenthesis after `self.setter`) to defer calling the function until the user clicks the button.

---

In other news, you have a few lines like:

```
self.someWidgetName = SomeWidget(...).grid(...)
```

In this case, `self.someWidgetName` will *always* have the value of `None` since that is the return value of `Widget.grid`.  This could lead to confusion of people (you!) reading your code because all of those class members *seem* like they should hold widget instances when they don't in reality.  A much better practice is to do what you've done with `self.trialOut` -- Use the geometry manager on a separate line:

```
self.someLabel = Label(...)
self.someLabel.grid(...)
```

Comment: I was under the impression that the command isn't executed until the button is clicked, allowing this code to execute as it is. Is there a parameter for the button that I should know about?

Comment: @Wotaod -- `command` expects that you pass a function (which gets executed later when the button is clicked).  You are passing the _return value_ of a function rather than the function itself.

Comment: Good to know regarding the geometry manager. I had seen several references sending widgets to the geometry from the same line as their creation, and heresofar it has appeared to work for me.

Comment: @Wotaod -- I've never seen those references, but I believe you.  I've seen so many users make that same mistake on StackOverflow questions so many times that it has to be in some resource somewhere.